# Git not asking for credentials

Tags: git, ssl, credentials

I am trying to fetch a git repository with the command as follows

```
git fetch -o origin (https://git.mydomain.com/path/to/repo.git)
```

However it results in

```
fatal: No such file or directory
```

If I add the credentials into the url as such:

```
git fetch -o origin (https://username:password@git.mydomain.com/path/to/repo.git)
```

It works like a charm

How can I get the url without credentials to work?

Edit: As the commands were part of an npm install here are sample commands you could replicate the issue with outside of it..

```
git clone -o origin https://git.mydomain.com/path/to/repo.git
```

Comment: You should describe your server-side setup.

Comment: This is only happening on one computer. The other computers, using the same credentials are working. So it is definitely client-side configuration

Comment: Please show actual commands, not some wrong examples.

Comment: the repositories are internal and cannot be reached from the outside...

Comment: It doesn't matter. As I see at least two errors in each command you've provided, there can be more errors in things you actually run.

Answer (score 0):

This should be managed with [git credential storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage), like the GCM (Git Credential Manager) [for Windows](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) or for [Mac/Linux](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Mac-and-Linux).

And if you have the same credentials for multiple URLs, with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), a configuration element used for credential subsystem can now **use wildcard pattern** to specify for which set of URLs the entry applies.

See [commit 46fd7b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46fd7b390034eb5dde6a3f955e677c5260e4d10c), [commit 82eb249](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82eb249853868582d8ba65e3afc5a7dcaeb620ea), [commit 588c70e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/588c70e10f3511f85110512da97b188f3c581e53), [commit 732f934](https://github.com/git/git/commit/732f93440831a9253ad5b9bd16a81e25e1901f22), [commit 3fa0e04](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3fa0e046679b69ee7039a60674e9b16f83780e85) (20 Feb 2020) by [brian m. carlson (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2cbb058](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cbb0586697585995908c325a0c70aad37602274), 05 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46fd7b390034eb5dde6a3f955e677c5260e4d10c): allow wildcard patterns when matching config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>
> In some cases, a user will want to use a specific credential helper for a wildcard pattern, such as **`https://*.corp.example.com`**.
>
> We have code that handles this already with the urlmatch code, so let's use that instead of our custom code.
>
> Since the urlmatch code is a superset of our current matching in terms of capabilities, there shouldn't be any cases of things that matched previously that don't match now.
>
> However, in addition to wildcard matching, we now use partial path matching, which can cause slightly different behavior in the case that a helper applies to the prefix (considering path components) of the remote URL.
>
> While different, this is probably the behavior people were wanting anyway.
>
> Since we're using the urlmatch code, we need to encode the components we've gotten into a URL to match, so add a function to percent-encode data and format the URL with it.
>
> We now also no longer need to the custom code to match URLs, so let's remove it.
>
> Additionally, the urlmatch code always looks for the best match, whereas we want all matches for credential helpers to preserve existing behavior.
>
> Let's add an optional field, `select_fn`, that lets us control which items we want (in this case, all of them) and default it to the best-match code that already exists for other users.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), the parser used for `credential.<URL>.<variable>` configuration is updated to handle `<URL>`s with '`/`' in them correctly.

See [commit b44d011](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b44d0118ac5074215ece7ae2bb86ad0713f70674) (27 Apr 2020) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fd65fc3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd65fc3960a972ab2f03b94d08f0e421d9ee22bb), 05 May 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b44d0118ac5074215ece7ae2bb86ad0713f70674): fix matching URLs with multiple levels in path
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ilya Tretyakov</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Carlo Marcelo Arenas Belón</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: brian m. carlson</sup>
>
> [46fd7b3900](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46fd7b390034eb5dde6a3f955e677c5260e4d10c) ("`credential`: allow wildcard patterns when matching config", 2020-02-20, Git v2.26.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cbb0586697585995908c325a0c70aad37602274) listed in [batch #0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/)) introduced support for matching credential helpers using urlmatch.
>
> In doing so, it introduced code to percent-encode the paths we get from the credential helper so that they could be effectively matched by the urlmatch code.
>
> Unfortunately, that code had a **bug**: **it percent-encoded the slashes in the path, resulting in any URL path that contained multiple levels (i.e., a directory component) not matching.**
>
> We are currently the only caller of the percent-encoding code and could simply change it not to encode slashes.
>
> However, we still want to encode slashes in the username component, so we need to have both behaviors available.
>
> So instead, let's add a flag to control encoding slashes, which is the behavior we want here, and use it when calling the code in this case.
>
> Add a test for credential helper URLs using multiple slashes in the path, which our test suite previously lacked, as well as one ensuring that we handle usernames with slashes gracefully.
>
> Since we're testing other percent-encoding handling, let's add one for non-ASCII UTF-8 characters as well.